# RSS reader which caches pages

Tags: software-recommendation, rss

Does anyone know of an RSS reader for linux which will cache the pages that are linked to in the stories? Really handy for travellers who are often out or wifi range.

Comment: Jorge, out of interest, what do you need to change in my posts? Just asking so that I can get it right in the future. Would be helpful if you posted changes so that users were nudged in the correct stylistic direction, to save you work in the future.

Comment: to see the changes, click here http://askubuntu.com/posts/8192/revisions

Comment: The revision link lukasz posted is available as a timestamp link right next to "edited", e.g. right now it says "Oct 19 at 2:10".  You can see the revisions for any post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Naufrago!](http://gnomefiles.org/content/show.php/Naufrago!?content=132322) seems to be intended particularly for offline use.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll accept it if no better ones are submitted soon.